# failed to show spinner at the center of a div

Tags: css

I have a div with some content and I trying to show a spinner at the center of the div.

**html**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="loader"> </div>
  <p>
    The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[1] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
    Indented paragraphs demonstrated in the US Constitution
    In ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences into paragraphs was a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversized capital letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of the text. This style can be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not commonly.[2] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting the first line. This style can be seen in the (handwritten) United States Constitution from 1787. For additional ornamentation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can be added to the inter-paragraph whitespace, or put in the indentation space.
  </p>
</div>
```

in the above code I want to show the spinner at the center of the div with a class name as 'parent'

**css**

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
}

    .loader {
      margin: 100px auto;
      font-size: 25px;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      text-indent: -9999em;
      -webkit-animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
      animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes load5 
    {
      0%,
      100% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #ffffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      }`
      12.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      }` 
      25% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      37.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      50% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      62.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      75% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      87.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff;
      }`
    }
    @keyframes load5 {
      0%,
      100% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #ffffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      }`
      12.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      }`
      25% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      37.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      50% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      62.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      75% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
      }`
      87.5% `{
        box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff;
      }`
    }
```

my issue is I failed to center the spinner in the center of it's parent div.How can I show the spinner with a transparent background-color at the center of the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

to ur loader

The top and left values will almost center the loader, but not exactly to center. The top-left point will be at the center.

This line  `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` will fix it, by pushing itself 50% of its own height and width in the left and the top direction, thus centering the loader.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.loader {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
    animation: load5 1.1s infinite ease;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: #e65757;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load5 {
  0%,
  100% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #ffffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  ` 12.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  ` 25% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 37.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 50% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 62.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 75% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 87.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff;
  }
  `
}

@keyframes load5 {
  0%,
  100% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em #ffffff, 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  ` 12.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  ` 25% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 2.5em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 37.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 50% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0em 2.5em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 62.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em #ffffff, -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 75% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -2.6em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  ` 87.5% ` {
    box-shadow: 0em -2.6em 0em 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.8em -1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2.5em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 1.75em 1.75em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0em 2.5em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), -1.8em 1.8em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -2.6em 0em 0 0em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -1.8em -1.8em 0 0em #ffffff;
  }
  `
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="loader"> </div>
  <p>
    The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation
    became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[1] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle
    Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way. Indented paragraphs demonstrated in the US Constitution In ancient manuscripts, another means to divide sentences into paragraphs was
    a line break (newline) followed by an initial at the beginning of the next paragraph. An initial is an oversized capital letter, sometimes outdented beyond the margin of the text. This style can be seen, for example, in the original Old English manuscript
    of Beowulf. Outdenting is still used in English typography, though not commonly.[2] Modern English typography usually indicates a new paragraph by indenting the first line. This style can be seen in the (handwritten) United States Constitution from
    1787. For additional ornamentation, a hedera leaf or other symbol can be added to the inter-paragraph whitespace, or put in the indentation space.
  </p>
</div>
```